# Why can't I add a column with tinytext?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a column to an existing table in mysql.

I am trying to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD online TINYTEXT(3) AFTER name;
```

But it causes this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(3) AFTER name' at line 1

Comment: remove the `(3)`. Tinytext does neither need nor support this. If you only want 3 characters, don't use tinytext, use char or varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `(3)`. Tinytext does neither need nor support this. If you only want 3 characters, don't use tinytext, use char or varchar.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `online` TINYTEXT AFTER `name`;
```

Comment: I actually wanted to accept your answer as the solution, but I can't since it is a comment... If you repost it as an answer I'll accept it. Then maybe there is no reason to downvote my question?